# Display all data when no value is selected from dropdown list

Tags: visualforce, selectlist

I am displaying a dropdown list of Accounts on VF page which is displaying other field's values on selecting the Accounts. This functionality is working fine. My additional requirement is I need to display all the data of other fields (FieldA and FieldB) when I'm not selecting any Account from dropdown list (i.e at the time of "All"). Kindly help.

Page-

```
<apex:page controller="AccountController" action="{!showrecord}">
 <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Accounts" rendered="{!flag}">
            <apex:outputLabel value=""/>
            <apex:selectlist value="{!selectedName}" size="1" id="values"> 
                <apex:SelectOptions value="{!AccountList}"/>  
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!showrecord}" reRender="acc"/>          
            </apex:selectlist>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrapList}" var="v" id="acc">                 
                <apex:column value="{!v.act.FieldA__c}" width="10%"/>
                <apex:column value="{!v.act.FieldB__c}" width="10%"/>                                                  
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>  
        <apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!NOT(flag)}">            
        </apex:pageBlockSection>        
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller-

```
public class AccountController{    
Public String selectedName {get;set;}
Public String newACCName{get;set;}
Public Account objACC{get;set;}    
Public List<Wrapper> wrapList{get;set;}
Public List<Account> acList{get;set;}
public Boolean flag{get;set;}

Public AccountController(){
    flag =  true;
  objACC = new Account(); 
}


public List<SelectOption> getAccountList(){
    List<SelectOption> AccountList = new List<SelectOption>();
    AccountList.add(new SelectOption('','------------All-----------')); 
    List<Account> actList = [Select id, name, FieldA__c, FieldB__c from Account];
    for(Account acc :actList){
        AccountList.add(new SelectOption(acc.Id,acc.Name));     
    }
   return AccountList;    
}

Public void showrecord(){
    wrapList = new List<Wrapper>();
    if(selectedName == ''){
    acList = [select id, Name, FieldA_c, FieldB__c, FieldC__c from Account];
  }
else{
   acList = [select id, Name, FieldA_c, FieldB__c, FieldC__c from Account where id =: selectedName];
  }
    for(Account acc :acList)      
    {
        wrapList.add(new Wrapper(false,ac));
    }        
    system.debug('inmethod'+ acList);
}
Public Class Wrapper{
    Public Boolean ischeck{get;set;}
    Public Account act{get;set;}
    Public Wrapper (Boolean ischeck, Account act){
        This.ischeck=ischeck;
        This.act=act;
    }    
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your action method, put an extra logic to identify the "All" selection.

```
Public void showrecord(){
    wrapList = new List<Wrapper>();
    if(selectedName == ''){
        acList = [select id, Name, FieldA_c, FieldB__c, FieldC__c from Account];
    }
    else{
       acList = [select id, Name, FieldA_c, FieldB__c, FieldC__c from Account where id =: selectedName];
    }
    for(Account acc :acList)
    {
        wrapList.add(new Wrapper(false,ac));
    }        
    system.debug('inmethod'+ acList);
}
```

In addition to this, if you need to display a default search result as well, (i.e. when you load the page you are having the "All" results) simply add the `action='{!showrecord}'` attribute to your page.

Comment: Thanks @highfive for your inputs. I tried your code but it didn't showed me all data on selecting none of the available options. I have updated the code. Kindly suggest if Im missing something.

Comment: Put a `System.debug(selectedName)` statement just inside the `showRecord` method and see what you get when selecting "All" option. Also check what  `wrapList` will hold at this time.